# How to assign value of field based on other rows fields values in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, window-functions

I have an [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_(PBX)) cdr database with rows representing every "call" (it's actually multiple rows per call depending on if it's inbound, outbound, local) executed inside my office.

I have 3 extensions (200, 201, 202) so for every inbound call asterisk generates 3 rows with the same 'uniqueid' and a 'disposition' indicating whether said extension answered or not a said call.

I utilize this data to generate a Call History listview for a small desktop program running on every desk and I need to show only the calls of a given extension and FROM HERE stems my question:

I should show every inbound call of my extension BUT if a call disposition is 'NO ANSWER' BUT STILL someone else answered that specific call i shoudn't show the call since it is not actually missed; to say it in other words, I should show a call missed only if EVERY extension missed it (has NO ANSWER disposition).

I thought of flagging a row with a bool field conditioned on whether or not there is at least one row with the same 'uniqueid' that has disposition 'ANSWER'. I added the column 'isToDiscard' but I don't now how to go on; maybe triggers could be used but i couldn't do it.

Am I approaching the problem in a meaningful way? I kinda did this in the backend but this flag or approach whould make everything easier.

[image: screen of my query and result]

Answer (score 0):

We can identify the non-answered calls with a window function:

```
select *
from (
    select c.*, 
        max(disposition = 'ANSWERED') over(partition by uniqueid) as was_answered
    from cdr c
) c
where was_answered = 0
```

Expression `disposition = 'ANSWER'` returns `1` if the value matches, else `0` : taking the maximum of that value over a group of calls (as identify by a *partition* rows sharing the same `uniqueid`) tells us if the call was answered by any desk. We can the use that information to filter.

If you want to filter the resultset for a specific desk (extension), then you can simply add the filter to the *outer query*.

Comment: When i try this query i got this message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by uniqueid) as was_answered
    from cdr c
) c
where was_answered' at line 4"

Comment: "Windowing" functions, such as OVER(...) are not available until MariaDB 10.2 (and MySQL 8.0). My Bad... I'll consider upgrading the db. Thanks